# Eclipse Genymotion error: Java was started but returned exit code=-805306369

Tags: java, android, eclipse, genymotion

I've been using Genymotion android emulator for development purpose with eclipse for 4/5 months. Everything was fine until once suddenly Genymotion plugin was not responding properly and after closing the window, it shows the following error:

[image: Java error screenshot]

My PC OS is Windows 8 Pro 64 bit. I have installed jdk 7 of both 64 bit and 32 bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be of jdk versions you are using.Try Using only 64 bit version of jdk in your system and configure it.Then let us know if you face errors.

Comment: But I also need 32 bit version for some other programs to run. And It was fine before.

Comment: No it's not the porblem. I needed to reinstall windows. So, I removed every programs and reinstalled everything. Now I only have java 64 bit version installed but still the same problem.

Comment: This was the exact problem and got solved because of conflictions of these 2 versions.